# Visual Studio: can not publish my solution in my team foundation server using git

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating an application with Visual Studio 2015 and I'd like to start online version control with Git.

In other words, I have to publish my solution to my Team Foundation Server, but I have problems. Please, see the image below.

http://s4.postimg.org/4fqvn4ei5/tfs.png

`"Could not create team project 'ERP'. Please try again."`

In reality I don't have to create a new project in my team foundation server, because it already exists and visual studio found it automatically through my hotmail account.

At beginning I was using team foundation version control (tfvc), but now I want to use git. I was able to create a git local repository, but now I'm not able to publish it in my tfs.

Comment: TFS or VSO?  
did you create git team project there?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the difference between VSO and TFS... as far as I understand VSO is based on TFS but TFS can exist without VSO.

This is the user interface if it can help: http://postimg.org/image/hkldc82nf/

Do you confirm what Daniel Mann wrote? Do you have to specify which version control you want to use when you create a team project? The problem is that the project was created by an other person, and I don't know how it was configured.

Comment: yes, Daniel is right. If you have TFVC project, you need to create new Git project. It isn't possible to modify existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a team project backed by Git. TFVC and Git currently cannot co-exist in the same team project.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem. I have to create a new project in visual studio online and configure it to use git, right?
Is it possible to modify the version control setting of an existing project, so that I don't have to delete the one I already have?

Comment: Nope. The backing source control method can't be changed.